# Can't generate makefiles in MonoDevelop 5.5

Tags: development

I'm trying to build a package on Ubuntu 15.04 using MonoDevelop 5.5, and I can't generate makefiles. When I press the Project menu, there is no such option. When I try to create package, I only have the option to make a tarball of sources or binaries, but I want make files also. When I try to use the mdtool, I'm greeted with this response:

```
$ mdtool generate-makefiles NetworkTester.sln --simple-makefiles -d:default-config
Tool 'generate-makefiles' not found.

Available tools:
- build: Project build tool
- dbgen: Parser database generation tool
- project-export: Project conversion tool
- gsetup: Graphical add-in setup utility
```

What's going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036587/mdtool-generation-of-makefile

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
mdtool gsetup
```

and enable Project Import and Export / Makefile generation.

After this, your command should do something :o) but I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045602/481812) that

> Makefile integration in MonoDevelop is kind of an abandoned project